# How to use AS_PATH attribute in scapy for BGP?

Tags: python, scapy, bgp

I try to set the `AS_PATH` attribute:

```
setAS=BGPPathAttr(type_flags="Transitive", type_code="AS_PATH",attr_len=None,attribute=None)
```

But Wireshark is saying that it is a malformed `AS_PATH` attribute.

I already have the other mandatory attributes in my *Update message* packet and they're doing well.

How to send a [`BGP`](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/security/glossary/what-is-bgp/) *Update message* crafted packet with correct attributes?

Comment: What did you research? Can you post the error-message from Wireshark. Also see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104621/setting-up-bgp-layer-using-scapy) for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did like this and works.

```
setAS = BGPPathAttr(
    type_flags="Transitive",
    type_code="AS_PATH",
    attr_len=None,
    attribute=BGPPAAS4BytesPath(
        segments=BGPPAAS4BytesPath().ASPathSegment(
                                                    segment_type=2(AS_SEQUENCE), segment_length=None, segment_value=[1234]
                                                )
                                )
    )
```

When we have variables asking the `"length"`, please use `"None"`.