# Can't specify AS_PATH attribute in BGP packet [Scapy]

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, bgp

When using Scapy, I am unable to set the AS_PATH attribute. I have tried following the answer provided in this StackOverflow page [How to use AS_PATH attribute in scapy for BGP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72734584/how-to-use-as-path-attribute-in-scapy-for-bgp), but it did not work. I have also tried inputting the following statements in the **attribute** parameter, but I have not been able to.

```
setAS=BGPPathAttr(type_flags="Transitive", type_code="AS_PATH", attribute="2")
setAS=BGPPathAttr(type_flags="Transitive", type_code="AS_PATH",attr_len=None,attribute=BGPPAAS4BytesPath(segments=BGPPAAS4BytesPath().ASPathSegment(segment_type=2,segment_length=None,segment_value=[2])))
```

My desired outcome is to send a packet with the AS_PATH value of 2.

Answer (score 0):

AS_PATH is well-known mandatory, not transitive.

Comment: Does this mean that the AS_PATH variable cannot be edited?

Comment: No, it means "type_flags="Transitive", type_code="AS_PATH"" above is wrong --not sure what it will trigger.